# Local network analyzer with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lan, network-monitoring

I would like to make network monitoring dashboard with react.What I'm trying to do is get the LAN devices all information and show them on react like [Net Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.techet.netanalyzerlite.an&hl=tr) mobile app.But not mobile , with reactjs.
I can access a few simple data using some node modules, but I couldn't run the same codes on react.
The node modules and outputs I use are as follows :

```
var network = require('network'); 
network.get_public_ip(function(err, ip) {
  console.log(err || ip); // should return your public IP address
})
network.get_private_ip(function(err, ip) {
  console.log(err || ip); // err may be 'No active network interface found'.
})
network.get_gateway_ip(function(err, ip) {
  console.log(err || ip); // err may be 'No active network interface found.'
})




network.get_interfaces_list(function(err, list) {
 list.forEach(item => console.log(item));
})
```

[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51qm2.png)

The second module I use

```
const find = require('local-devices');

find().then(devices => {


  console.log(devices);

})
```

[output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8nII.png)

When I use this modules on react I get some errors like this.

[react errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Njal.png)

I have to improve the interface with react.How should I proceed?What is the most logical way?

Comment: i doubt those apis needed to do the monitoring are available in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

`network` is a Node.js package. It won't work in the browser.

Solutions:-

1. SSR - You can render the React app using Server-side rendering. And Using those network packages you can fetch the information at the server-side.
2. Client-side rendering - You need to develop a service/API that returns you with all the information needed at the client-side.

Comment: As I undertand I should use the react for frontend and develop a service for backend.Am I right? @Abhishek

Comment: yeah, you can also check SSR - https://alligator.io/react/server-side-rendering